# Divide price into groups by using K-means

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

There is a task of dividing product prices into 3 groups {high, avg, low} groups of prices. Have tried to implement it via K-means by using sklearn package. Data is in pandas Dataframe format of float64 type

```
dfcl
Out[173]:
                price
product_option_id   
    10012|0 372.15
    10048|0 11.30
    10049|0 12.26
    10050|0 6.20
    10051|0 5.90
    10052|0 9.00
    10053|0 11.10
    10054|0 9.30
    10055|0 4.20
    10056|0 5.60


# Convert DataFrame to matrix
mat = dfcl.as_matrix()
# Using sklearn
km = sklearn.cluster.KMeans(n_clusters=3)
km.fit(mat)
# Get cluster assignment labels
labels = km.labels_
# Format results as a DataFrame
results = pd.DataFrame(data=labels, columns=['cluster'], index=dfcl.index)
```

Have gotten the results but it seems so unbalanced between groups

```
print('Total features -', len(results))
print('Cluster 0 -',len(results.loc[results['cluster'] == 0]))
print('Cluster 1 -',len(results.loc[results['cluster'] == 1]))
print('Cluster 2 -',len(results.loc[results['cluster'] == 2]))

Total features - 5222
Cluster 0 - 4470
Cluster 1 - 733
Cluster 2 - 19
```

By the way, when I recount fitting data some times happens that data highly swaps between clusters. Is there any way to solve the problem with so unbalanced data between groups and leave the cluster names static to recount algorithm? I've also tried normalizing data using `preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()` and it didn't help.
Maybe there are some cluster algorithms that can help me do what I want or any others hacks?

```
Total features - 5222
Cluster 0 - 733
Cluster 1 - 4470
Cluster 2 - 19
```

Comment: The output of first and second fitting shown here is same. Same clusters are made as before. Just that the label of the cluster changed. It doesnt matter what the label of cluster is because clustering is a unsupervised task. What matters is that same points should be in those clusters. So you can check that 4470 points in cluster 0 in first fitting is the same as 4470 points in cluster 1 in second.

Comment: Yes, there are the same points. Product 10012|0 372.15 didn't get into high cluster even the price is so huge. How can I adjust algorithm to notice so outliers even if they doesn't have huge distance from cluster centers?

Comment: Have you checked the max and min prices of points in each cluster? What did you observe. Isn't it better to manually assign the ranges for the clusters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your data distribution is already skewed. K-means minimizes squared errors; it does not care about balanced clusters.

Furthermore, k-means does not produce "low" or "high" - you need to assign such semantics yourself. You cannot assume that cluster 2 is "high".

It may be worth looking at a histogram of the data, then define thresholds for "low" and "high" as you seem fit.